# Android Studio: Set Color Tint on Icon within a TabItem

Tags: android, menu, menuitem, imageicon, tint

I'm using the TabLayout for my menu with Icon buttons.
Is it possible to tint the icons via XML in drawables?

android:tint doesn't work with a TabItem element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it coding part, try this

```
private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);


    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: setOnTabSelectedListener() is deprecated. I used "addOnTabSelectedListener" instead.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set tint through XML there is one way. Is custom layout for `TabItem` which is set through attribute `android:layout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawable"
        android:layout="@layout/custom_tab" />
```

Where `custom_tab` layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.view.TintableImageView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:tint_color="@color/red" />
```

Source of `TintableImageView` you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/MarkoMilos/5b225832cfd8fe1994e0).

This approach gives you flexibility if you want to use different icon colors for different selector states, just create color selector file and set it as a tint color and it works

```
app:tint_color="@color/selector_tab"
```

Comment: Wrong. There is not one way.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a much simpler solution,
in the layout file add this attribute to the TabLayout:

```
app:tabIconTint="@color/desired_color_or_selector"
```

if you want to preserve the color state (enable/disable/selected) give it a color selector like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/enabled_color" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/disabled_color" />
</selector>
```